# How to get Doctrine ArrayCollection from createNativeQuery

Tags: jquery, doctrine, native

Trying to get doctrines ArrayCollection from createNativeQuery however getting null returned and can't find what am i doing wrong here.
Everything seems to be done according to [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html) however it doesn't seem to work for me.
The code below:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult(CurrencyExchangeRate::class, 'u');

$rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'rate', 'rate');
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult(Currency::class, 'a', 'u', 'currency');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'currency_id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'name', 'name');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'code', 'code');
$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'symbol', 'symbol');

$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT u.rate,a.id as currency_id, a.name,a.code,a.symbol
                                    FROM currency_exchange_rates_new u
                                    INNER JOIN currencies_new a on u.currency_id = a.id
                                    WHERE u.update_time=(SELECT MAX(update_time) FROM currency_exchange_rates_new u2 WHERE u2.currency_id=u.currency_id)
                                    GROUP BY u.currency_id',$rsm);

$currency_exchange_rates = $query->getResult();
foreach ($currency_exchange_rates as $currency_exchange_rate) {
    error_log(var_export($currency_exchange_rate,true)."\n",0);
}
```

**The error log outputs**

NULL

NULL

NULL

NULL

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here?